# How should I fix to let it works?

Tags: list, printing, range

enter image description here

Why I follow the book said but it still couldn't work?

```
list1 = range(1, 10, 2)
print(list(list1))
```

Comment: I work for me and got the output [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]. Please clear your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.